# Bluetooth speaker doesn't show up in output devices list

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, bluetooth-speaker

I'm trying to get my bluetooth speaker working with Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome.
It connects but doesn't show up in sound output devices list.

I've tried few suggestions

```
sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Output:

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. In [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=196689) is pointed [this solution](https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-disable-pulseaudio-and-sound-in-gdm/).

Basically, you have to create/edit the file `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/client.conf`

And add the following configuration lines

`autospawn = no
daemon-binary = /bin/true`

And give to GDM the ownership

`sudo chown gdm:gdm /var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/client.conf`

Retart GDM and it is solved

Comment: Thanks, I've given up on BT speaker but if I try it again I'll let you know how it went

Comment: I can confirm that this worked on Ubuntu (with Gnome shell) on 17.04! Thanks so much! (btw I got Failure to load module, not the error the OP got)

Comment: At the sudo command, I get this error: chown: invalid user: ‘gdm:gdm’

Comment: @AbhinavKumar my original answer was for Ubuntu 16.04. What Ubuntu version are you using? Maybe the `gdm` user does not exist. You can check if it exists running `cat /etc/passwd | grep gdm`

Comment: @Manuel this is the output of the command you suggested: Debian-gdm:x:130:138:Gnome Display Manager:/var/lib/gdm3:/bin/false

Comment: @AbhinavKumar, it seems that your user is not `gdm` but `Debian-gdm`. You can try using `chown` with `Debian-gdm`, but I cannot garantee that it is going to work. What distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0):

for Ubuntu 20.04 this worked for me:

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
sudo service bluetooth restart
```